# reposition UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a Custom UITableViewCell (no tableview only the cell entrierly on its own in a UIView class), I can get the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark to display normally in the UITableViewCell however I am woundering if there is a way to bring it in form the edge a little?

this is how I am setting my accessory type.

```
selectAllCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a subclass of UITableViewCell, and then create your own accessoryView.

In your CustomTableViewCell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.accessoryView = view;
    }
    return self;
 }
```

Comment: okay cool will try that now :) I know what you mean re: self.accessoryView.frame but not layoutSubviews:

Comment: @HurkNburkS I have edited my answer with a little code. Hope to help.

Comment: accessoryView will be nil since it has not be set with a UIView.

Comment: okay thank you for the extra code going to look into.. I was thinking something a little different. I have never done my subviews like this before.. currently I just have them being set up in my viewDidLoad method.

Comment: accessoryView and accessoryType are two separate things.

Comment: yea.. not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using a UITableView, create your own UIView and add your own check icon and put it wherever you like.

Comment: is there a standard check icon in ios that I can call? It's just that I want the same tick icon.. and if i retrofit my own tick it will look abit horrible..